# Sending message to a specific instance of view model in region

Tags: prism, eventaggregator

I am using prism and wpf. I have a view which might have multiple instances with corresponding viewmodels. The problem is I need to do some thing on the basis of some event in the viewmodel for the specific instance which is hosted in a specific region. I am thinking to use event aggregator to subscribe to the event, problem is each viewmodel creation will subscribe to the same event and on publishing, each will receive the same event which I don't want but want only the region hosted instance to receive the message and process and others to ignore it.

In a nutshell I want to send message only to the user control's viewmodel which is hosted in a specific region even if the usercontrol is hosted in any other region.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way of doing this is using **EventAggregator** indeed, but using a ***Filter*** on the Subscriptions.

Each **ViewModel** instance would have a delegate method in order to decide if that instance would handle the **Event** or not. ***Filters*** on **Events** would be performed as follows:

```
public class MultipleViewModel
{
    private IRegionManager regionManager;

    public MultipleViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager, IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        this.regionManager = regionManager;
        this.eventAggregator.GetEvent<SpecificViewModelHandledEvent>().Subscribe(SpecificViewModelEventHandler, ThreadOption.PublisherThread, false, ViewModelInstanceFilter);
    }

    public bool ViewModelInstanceFilter()
    {
        return this == this.regionManager.Regions["SpecificRegion"].GetView("ViewName").DataContext;
    }

    public void SpecificViewModelEventHandler()
    {
        // Handle the Event on the particular ViewModel instance.
    }
}
```

Therefore, that delegate method would compare the current **ViewModel** instance with the **ViewModel** instance registered on the specific **Region**. So that only instance would return ***true*** on the filter and it only would handle the **Published Event**.

For more information you could look at the following **MSDN Prism Guide** chapter:

- [9: Communicating Between Loosely Coupled Components](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx#sec16)

I hope this helped, 
Regards.

---

**UPDATE**

Regarding the comment's question about generalizing the solution, I would like to mention that a more suitable implementation could have be done with separate **ViewModels**. Otherwise, you would not need to get one only instance handling the **Event**. They all should have the same responsibility.

Anyway, I could think of one possible workaround if more than one instance is registered on the same **Region**: As you would need to identify the desired instance through all the others, the user could check or set a property on the desired **View** instance for being the "***Responsive View***", so it can be evaluated then on the ***Event Filter***.

When each **ViewModel** initializes, you could set a bool **Propery** to false, and bind it to its **View** on a **CheckBox** for example or anything alike. Then you could properly check the **View** you would want to handle the **Event** while the other instances would remain unchecked, filtering this way the published event.

With this new approach, you would need to modify the ***ViewModelInstanceFilter()*** method so that it evaluates this checked **Property**. And if you like, you could add a *Service* that verifies no more than one instance is checked at the same time.

I hope this helped you.
Regards.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. This will work good for a specific scenario. Now, can you provide a generalized solution for that? like how to make communicate two specific viewmodel instances ? whether they be in different regions or same regions. Thanks.

Comment: ...Like View A needs to send message/event to one of many opened instances of View B through its viewmodel.

Comment: Hello Abdul, I've updated the answer with the generalized scenario. Please notice as I explained above, that a different approach with separated **View/ViewModels**, I mean not being the same class, may have been more suitable for this scenario. Regards.